# Inserting Boxes in Netbeans designer

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout

I'm trying to insert some spacers into a layout on `JPanel`. I've got 3 buttons and I'd like to put something similar to `Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0))` between them. Netbeans 6.9.1 doesn't seem to have an option to create them - is that true? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to set the `JPanel` to use `BoxLayout` and modify a button's Pre- or Post-Adding code to include the desired `Component`:

```
this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
```

The generated code will look like this:

```
jButton1.setText("jButton1");
this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
add(jButton1);
this.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
```

You'll also need to `import javax.swing.Box`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple work around would be to add a JPanel with a custom preferred size.